# What methods can I use to pass the START TIME from PHPSCRIPT1 to PHPSCRIPT2?

Tags: php

I have a javascript quiz which gets question data via an ajax call to PHPSCRIPT1.

At the same time I do this, I get the START TIME of the quiz via PHPSCRIPT1 and pass it back to the quiz.

At the end of the quiz I will pass the answer data and START TIME on to PHPSCRIPT2.The info will be processed and then stored in a database.

**Rather than send the START TIME client side, I'd like to keep it on the server** and send it directly to PHPSCRIPT2, so that it can be sent to mysql along with the answer data in the one query.

Is this possible? If yes, **what methods can I use to pass the START TIME from PHPSCRIPT1 to PHPSCRIPT2?**
If no, but you know a better way to keep START TIME server side I'd love to hear it.
Thanks.

EXTRA: I'm trying to avoid data going client side for fear they may be able to change the data.

Comment: Take a look at [Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). Or create the DB record at the start and update it at the end. **(Link fixed)**

Comment: @DaveRandom Thanks I'll take a look at sessions. In regards to the DB, I'd like to avoid creating a record in case they don't finish the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to develop a quiz, puzzle or so you surely want to use sessions (be they PHP standard sessions or roll-your-own ones). I am not aware of any other mechanism, that reliably glues together different pages of a webapp.

So it would be natural to store the start time in the session.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will use Sessions.